# What is a geometric construction corresponding to elliptic curve addition for Sharygin-isosceles triangles?

Tags: elliptic-curves, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, triangles

NB: this is a cross-posting from [from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087522/what-is-a-geometric-construction-corresponding-to-elliptic-curve-addition-for-sh) after two months with no progress (despite a bounty). It's totally elementary but I think it's cute.

Consider the elliptic curve defined by the cubic:
$$
  a^3 + a^2b + ab^2 + b^3 + (a^2 + ab + b^2)c - (a+b)c^2 - c^3 = 0
$$
in $\mathbb{P^2}$ with distinguished point $[1, -1, 0]$ as identity.

Recently I learned that the real points of the identity component of this curve naturally parameterise Euclidean triangles with a neat property. Specifically they are scalene triangles such that the triangle formed by intersecting angle bisectors with opposite sides is isosceles. Here's an example:

[image: An isosceles extriangle]

(The triangle in red, constructed from one internal and two external angle bisectors, is isosceles.)

Let's call this property $P$. See [here](http://olivernash.org/2016/12/18/sharygins-group-of-triangles/index.html) for a fuller discussion, with more pictures and a little history.

This means that given two triangles satisfying property $P$, there is a naturally associated third: their sum under elliptic curve addition. My questions are:

1. **Can we find a geometric construction for the sum of two of these triangles ?**
2. **Is there is a natural family of geometric objects parameterised by the non-identity component of the elliptic curve ?**

Comment: Somebody recently contacted me to point out that this geometry is discussed by Sharygin in a 1983 issue of Kvant, available online here: http://kvant.mccme.ru/1983/08/vokrug_bissektrisy.htm My lack of Russian presents a bit of a barrier for me, but perhaps the article contains relevant ideas that others may be able to translate?